# Set stepper in second step in clarity design angular

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity, clarity

How can I set stepper in second step automatically when I open page in clarity design angular?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/clr-stepper-demo

Comment: How can I make it automatically open at init time to open page 2?

Comment: I Couldn't find it in the docs

Answer (score 0):

You can set an id for the first next button.

```
     <button id="firstButton" clrStepButton="next">next</button>
```

And you can click it in `ngOnInit()`.

```
     ngOnInit() 
       { 
         let el: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('firstButton');
         el.click();
       }
```

Comment: get error such as input not valid even if there have value

Comment: You can try it in **ngAfterViewInit()**.

Comment: yes i try it in ngAfterViewInit() but error such as Cannot read property 'valid' of null